# Trouble Opening Category Tab by Default (Layered Navigation)

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation

In accordance with other posts/answers I've seen on this issue, I've overridden `Magento_LayeredNavigation/templates/layer/view.html` and edited the `filter-options div` with

```
<div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "0", "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
```

This partly works -- changing the expand/collapse arrow to what it would look like if the category tab was expanded and setting aria-expanded to "true" -- but it doesn't actually expand. The content div has an inline `style="display: none;"`

If I try it with other tabs in the layered navigation, it works for them. Any reason why it wouldn't work for Category?

Edit: should note thank I'm inheriting blank, and not Luma.

Comment: You mean to show the div by default?

Comment: Yeah, to show the "Category" tab as expanded by default in the layered navigation.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve it by replacing below line:

```
<div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
```

with:

```
<div class="filter-options" id="narrow-by-list" data-role="content" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": "0", "multipleCollapsible": false}}'>
```

**"active": "0"** means first position filter which is category. If category position is second in your case then put **1** in place of **0**.

Comment: This is actually what I tried. Edited to reflect that, but in my initial post I had "active": [0], from when I was trying the range approach -- had the same effect either way. 

When I was trying the range (`"active" : [0, 1, 2]`) the other tabs in that array would be open by default, but not category tab.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting? This is working fine. Do you want multiple tabs open?

Comment: The category tab isn't expanded by default. I've tried to outline in my post that I've already tried the solutions offered in your answer and others, but that I'm still having issues with that particular tab. 

I only want category open. I was trying the array for troubleshooting's sake, and concluded that only the category tab is failing to expand by default.

Comment: What is the position of your category tab? First? If yes then try to flush your cache once.

Comment: Also check if you are using any extension for category.

Comment: I'm trying to say that it definitely doesn't work -- not a cacheing issue. Vanilla Magento, extending blank. It's probably some missing piece when trying to incorporate Luma's layered navigation into Blank, so I'm trying to ask what I should look into here.

Comment: You have done wrong then. You need to override the luma theme instead of blank

Comment: I'm not going to inherit Luma just for one feature. Inheriting Blank is perfectly acceptable and even encouraged. This is definitely possible, I just wanted some thoughts on troubleshooting.